# Inserting another filter command for a different column to be exported to txt

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following macro and I am looking to add a new criteria into it to create some txt files from a single column.
Basically export every row in column F to a new txt(with the name as the value in column E) if column G is 38, for each unique value in column E.
Hopefully, somebody can help

```
     Sub ExceltoTXT()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, c As range, ky As Variant, wb As Workbook, wPath As String, lr As Long
  Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  wPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
  If sh.AutoFilterMode Then sh.AutoFilterMode = False
  lr = sh.range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each c In sh.range("E2:E" & lr)
      .Item(c.Value) = Empty
    Next
   
    For Each ky In .Keys
      sh.range("E1").AutoFilter 1, ky
      Set wb = Workbooks.Add
      sh.AutoFilter.range.range("F2:F" & lr).Copy
      range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      wb.SaveAs wPath & ky & ".txt", FileFormat:=xlTextMSDOS
      wb.Close False
    Next
  End With
  sh.ShowAllData
End Sub
```

I need to insert this line

```
sh.range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="38"
```